# How to stub Restul-authentication's current_user method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I'm trying to run the following spec:

```
describe UsersController, "GET friends" do

  it "should call current_user.friends" do
    user = mock_model(User)
    user.should_receive(:friends)
    UsersController.stub!(:current_user).and_return(user)
    get :friends
  end

end
```

My controller looks like this

```
  def friends
    @friends = current_user.friends
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
    end
  end
```

The problem is that I cannot stub the current_user method, as when I run the test, I get:

```
Spec::Mocks::MockExpectationError in 'UsersController GET friends should call current
_user.friends'
Mock "User_1001" expected :friends with (any args) once, but received it 0 times[0m
./spec/controllers/users_controller_spec.rb:44:
```

current_user is a method from Restful-authentication, which is included in this controller. How am I supposed to test this controller?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to mock a user and then pass it into the login_as method to simulate logging in the user.

```
@user_session = login_as(stub_model(User))
UserSession.stubs(:new).returns(@user_session)
```

http://bparanj.blogspot.com/2006_12_01_archive.html

Comment: I've tried:

<pre>
  it "should call current_user.friends" do

    user = mock_model(User)
    user.should_receive(:friends)
    @user_session = login_as(user)
    get :friends
  end
</pre>

But it also didn't work. I thought that if I only call login_as it would be solved. Why's that?

Comment: you may also need to call:

UserSession.stubs(:new).returns(@user_session)

(or rename UserSession to the session model that restful-authentication created to handle sessions)